# Cleanup API data in pytest after post method

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, pytest

Is this optimal to delete data from API in this way?

```
def test_can_get_all_items():
   ### some code ...

    # CLEANUP DATA AFTER POST AND GET METHOD 

    try:
        for item_id in range(n):
            delete_response = requests.delete(ENDPOINT + f"delete-item?item_id={item_id+1}")
            assert delete_response.status_code == 200
    except:
        pass

    ### some code ...
```

I delete this with a Delete method but i dont know did this way is optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python's `yield` keyword for this purpose.

As an example:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def cleanup():
    yield
    print("do some cleanup")

def addition(a, b):
    return a + b

def test_addition(cleanup):
    result = addition(1, 2)
    assert result == 3
```

In this case, you pass the `cleanup` fixture to the `test_addition` test. The fixture will "yield" to the function (that is, will run the contents of the function) and when it is finished it will do something, in this case it will print "do some cleanup".

To test locally, run `pytest <file name>.py -c`. `-c` allow you to see the print in the terminal!

So in your case, you would add the delete in the `cleanup` function:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def cleanup():
   yield
   for item_id in range(n):
       delete_response = requests.delete(ENDPOINT + f"delete-item?item_id={item_id+1}")
```